# Is it possible to make part of a site on IIS only viewable from localhost?

Tags: iis, localhost

We've got a webserver running IIS. We'd like to run maybe a shared blog or something to keep track of information. Because of security issues, we'd like for that part to be only viewable from localhost so people have to remote in to use it.

So, to repeat my question, can part of a website be made viewable from localhost only?

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If so can you mark which one. I'd like to know how you actually solved this;-)

Comment: I'd be glad to, I still need to show the response to my friend who's going yo actually implement it. So it might be a few days but once I know, I'll accept an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In IIS6 you can bring up the properties for the web and click on the directory security tab. Click the button in the middle of the tab for editing the IP and Domain restrictions. On this tab set all computers as denied, then add an exception for the IPs you want to allow access to this site.

I am not sure how to configure this on IIS7. I looked but couldn't find it, if I find it I will edit this answer.

Edit: [Configuring IIS7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772206.aspx)

- Josh

Comment: Is it possible to do this in web.config? It looks like it from the command line [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772061%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) that something in the section system.webServer/security/authorization might work.

Answer (score 33):

For some one doing it in `IIS 8` / `Windows 2012`

1) In `Server Manager`, go to `Manage, Add Roles and Features`,  Next, Next (get to `Server Roles`), scroll down to `Web Server (IIS)`, expand that row, then expand `Web Server`, and finally expand `Security`. Make sure that **IP and Domain Restrictions** are installed.

2) In `IIS Manager`, drill down to the folder that you want to protect and left click select it. In the `Features View` of that folder select **IP and Domain Restrictions** In `Actions` choose `Edit Feature Settings`. Change `'Access for unspecified clients:'` to `'Deny'` then OK.

3) Finally go to `'Add Allow Entry'` In the `Action`s menu. Type in the Specific IP address of your server.

Now only requests coming from your server will be allowed access. Or any server that shares that IP address. So in a small network, the office could share the IP address between all of the PCs in that offices, so all of those PCs could access that folder.

Last but not least is to remember that if your network has a dynamic IP address, then if that IP changes, you will expose your blog admin folder to whoever is using that IP now. Also, everyone on that new IP address will lose access to your that folder...

Comment: I just tried the suggested method and I had to use 127.0.0.1  but I don't know the network science behind it.  The web site calling the other is in a different web site on the same IIS (windows server 2012 R2) and call it using http://localhost/...  This is a wcf service that is being called.

Comment: Same here: A service accessing another, restricted service as "localhost" on the same IIS. In this scenario we had to 'Add Allow Entry' with IP address 127.0.0.1 to get access to the restricted service.

Comment: Tip: After installing "IP and Domain Restrictions" I had to restart IIS Manager to see the new tool.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use bindings instead of IP restrictions. If you edit the bindings for the web site you want to restrict access to, you can select which IP address the site is available at. If you set the IP address to 127.0.0.1, then the site is only responding on this IP address, and this IP address will of course only work locally on the machine.

I've tested this using IIS 8.5.

Answer (score 4):

Should anyone wish to do this on the command line, this appears to work on IIS 7+

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity /+"[ipAddress='0',allowed='False']" /commit:apphost
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity /+"[ipAddress='127.0.0.1',allowed='True']" /commit:apphost
```

[Reference](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/add)

I initially wanted to do this in web.config to ease distribution, and it looked like the following might work:

```
<security>
    <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">    <!-- this line blocks everybody, except those listed below -->                
        <clear/> <!-- removes all upstream restrictions -->
        <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true"/>    <!-- allow requests from the local machine -->
    </ipSecurity>
</security>
```

but as you need to unlock the function in the central IIS config anyway there was no advantage over making the change directly using the first commands.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39870955/2279059, it is possible to configure the site's bindings to listen only on the loopback interface. This makes the site inaccessible from the network without having to use IP address restrictions.

To support both IPv4 and IPv6, add two bindings, one for `127.0.0.1` and one for `[::1]`, and set the hostname to `*`, so either IP address or `localhost` can be used to access it as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

To add a "local" site programmatically, you can use:

```
appcmd add site /name:MyLoalSite /bindings:http/127.0.0.1:7103:*,http/[::1]:7103:* /physicalPath:"C:\path\to\site\"
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the recommendations to use IIS "Directory Security" to block all IP address except 127.0.0.1 (localhost).

That said, I'm wondering how this strategy of requiring users to remote in could possibly be **more** secure. Wouldn't it be more secure (as well as much simpler) to use standard IIS authentication mechanisms rather than have to manage Windows roles and permissions on the server machine?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what you want to happen if an unauthorized user tries to visit it.

You could try to setup the specific section as a virtual directory, then deny view to anonymous users.  However, they will be prompted for login, and if they can login then they could see it.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the options present in the IIS MMC, you can also have a virtual directory only be accessible by certain IP-ranges. You could block everyone but 127.0.0.1. I have not tried this, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can grant or deny access to a site or folder from certain IPs to a site or folder.  In IIS, go into properties for the site or folder in question.

(1) Click to the "Diectory Security" Tab

(2) Click Edit Under the "IP Address and Domain Name Restriction" frame.

(3) Click "Denied Access" (This tells IIS to block every IP except those you list)

(4) Click "Add..."

(5) Click "Single Computer"

(6) Enter 127.0.0.1 (the IP of localhost)

Note that it is best to use an IP here (as I've described) rather than a domain name because domains can be easily forged using a hosts file.

Answer (score -4):

You could simply add this .NET to the top of the page.

```
string MyWebServerName = currentContext.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];

if ( MyWebServerName == "127.0.0.1" || MyWebServerName == "localhost" )
{
  // the user is local 
}
else
{
  // the user is NOT local
}
```

Comment: This isn't a scalable solution, as it requires access to source, has to be applied to every page, and doesn't allow for any flexibility after deployment.