# How to make IIS accessible only to localhost?

Tags: php, iis, system-administration

I'm a programmer, who dont know much about system administration.

I'm running a IIS php database (PostgreSQL) app on my localhost where I'm the only user. I want to make the webpages and the web server completely inaccessible from the internet. I have foreign ips in the event log. I'm worried about security as the app and computer has sensitive data. I want to shut all services down except for php for localhost access. How do I best do this?

If I could do without the inetpub\wwwroot completely that would be good, if I could get php to work in a normal local folder. Or maybe some settings (DefaultAppPool.config?) for shutting off the webserver completely to the outside world?

Comment: [URL Authorization Rules for IIS7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772206.aspx) - explains how to do this

Comment: You may find this answer useful also: [Is it possible to make part of a site on IIS only viewable from localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270284/is-it-possible-to-make-part-of-a-site-on-iis-only-viewable-from-localhost)

Answer (score 1):

Edit the site's binding and change the IP address from `(All Unassigned)` to `127.0.0.1`.