# Is there a way to disallow direct access of file but allow download via PHP script using IIS?

Tags: php, iis

I currently have a php script that serves downloads which you can view below. It works fine, but I wanted it so even if you had the direct link to a file you could not use that to download it. I'm currently using IIS 7. I saw that there is request filtering, but I didn't see how I could use that without blocking access to the files completely.

```
$extension = fileexten($filename);
if(($filename!= false)&&($fakename!=false&& @fopen($filename,'r')==true)){
$mime = contenttype($extension);
set_time_limit(0);
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0'); 
header("Content-Type:".$mime);
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: private', false);        
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$fakename.'.'.$extension);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

  if (ob_get_length() > 0) {
    ob_end_clean();
    }
flush();
readfile($filename);
}
else{
$error = "<h3>We could not find this file</h3>";} // If the filename or fake filename could not be retrieved. 
}
```

Comment: have you tried moving the files out of the public folder? That way there will be no public download link

Comment: I tried that, but no luck. The files would just download instantly and be empty.

Comment: if it's outside of the public folder, you shouldn't be able to get a link to the file.

Comment: I was talking about the download script. Would the download script be able to reach things outside of the public folder?

Comment: Yes, many MVC frameworks are outside of the public folder. However, looking into it more IIS doesn't look like it allows it. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270284/is-it-possible-to-make-part-of-a-site-on-iis-only-viewable-from-localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working by following these instructions

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22575734/104253